# ConvexHullMesh inconsistency for the decagon

Tags: bugs, regions, mesh

**Bug introduced in `V12.1.0` or earlier. Fixed in `V13.0.0` or earlier.**

---

I am seeing an inconsistency in `ConvexHullMesh` that I don't understand.
Here is

```
Rhull = ConvexHullMesh[pts8]
```

where the $8$ points (at bottom of post) determine a regular octagon-base pyramid:

---

[image]

---

As expected. When I change the base to a regular decagon instead

```
Rhull = ConvexHullMesh[pts10]
```

I get this:

---

[image]

---

The hull is just $3$ of the $10$ faces.

If it matters, I generate the points with sines & cosines converted with `//N`.
I tried leaving the points symbolic without observing a difference.

---

```
pts8={{1., 0., 0.}, {0.707107, 0.707107, 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, 
{-0.707107, 0.707107, 0.}, {-1., 0., 0.}, {-0.707107, -0.707107, 0.}, 
{0., -1., 0.}, {0.707107, -0.707107, 0.},{0, 0, 1}};

pts10={{1., 0., 0.}, {0.809017, 0.587785, 0.}, {0.309017, 0.951057, 
  0.}, {-0.309017, 0.951057, 0.}, {-0.809017, 0.587785, 0.}, {-1., 0.,
   0.}, {-0.809017, -0.587785, 0.}, {-0.309017, -0.951057, 
  0.}, {0.309017, -0.951057, 0.}, {0.809017, -0.587785, 0.}, {0., 0., 
  1.}};
```

---

Version 12.1.0.0.

Comment: There are bugs in `ConvexHullMesh` and much of the region/meshing stuff in _Mathematica_ and I wish they'd fix them. This one I've encountered myself and I believe it's because the points on the base lie in a plane. It incorrectly treats it as a degenerate arrangement. Add a very tiny amount of noise to the points and it meshes fine:  `ConvexHullMesh[pts10 + RandomReal[{-10^-6, 10^-6}, {Length[pts10], 3}]]`

Comment: @flinty: Thank you! If you make than an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It's just a workaround. I'll defer to others here who may know a better approach.

Comment: @flinty the method you have mentioned is sensitive to the level of noise. For example `RandomReal[{-10^-10, 10^-10}, ... ]` does not work if you iterate several times

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke did you report this bug to Wolfram? If not then let me know so that I can place one.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke .. btw I think your `pts8` and `pts10` are the same. `pts8 == pts10` returns `True`. Am i missing something??

Comment: ^ @AliHashmi yes I know, the closer you get to machine precision the worse the meshing which is why I picked a larger number 10^-6.

Comment: @AliHashmi: I did not report the bug. I don't know how to report a bug to Wolfram. (I thought the tag "bugs" might suffice, but I guess not.) Yes, feel free to place the bug report.

Comment: @AliHashmi: Sorry about overwriting pts8 with pts10 while editing.

Comment: It seems to go wrong at 8 points or more: `ConvexHullMesh[Append[Append[#, 0] & /@ CirclePoints[8], {0, 0, 1}]]`, however if you change the height of the cone then it works for example: `ConvexHullMesh[Append[Append[#, 0] & /@ CirclePoints[8], {0, 0, 2}]]`. The limit where it changes from bad to good is 1.189207115 or exactly 2^(1/4) for this particular cone of 8 sides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can workaround this issue with [`DelaunayMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DelaunayMesh.html):

```
BoundaryMesh[DelaunayMesh[pts10]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[`ConvexHullMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html) for the decagon case works fine on `V13.0.0`

> [image: decagon]

Comment: Great! The bug has been fixed.