# Why does ConvexHullMesh give inconsistent output stuctures?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

I know much of the stuff in ConvexHullMesh needs some TLC [convexhullmesh-inconsistency](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226064/convexhullmesh-inconsistency)

But, can anyone see why this would produce inconsistent output:

Case 1 (expected behavior):

```
sp = SpherePoints[5];
chSphere = ConvexHullMesh[sp];
Head[chSphere]
chSphere["Faces"]
```

Case 2 (expected behavior):

```
rp = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 3}];
chRP = ConvexHullMesh[rp];
Head[chRP]
chRP["Faces"]
```

Case 2 (inconsistent behavior)

```
dodCH = ConvexHullMesh[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Vertices"]]
Head[dodCH]
dodCH["Faces"]

dodCH = ConvexHullMesh[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Vertices"],  FlatFaces -> True] (*or using undocumented FlatFaces*)
Head[dodCH]
dodCH["Faces"]
```

I can find a work-around. But, I wish I didn't have to.

Comment: Surprisingly, if I start from a fresh kernel (using kernel quit) it doesn't work and I get the problem with "Faces". But if I execute in a different cell (and ignore the output of) `BoundaryMeshRegion@Dodecahedron[];` **then run your code again**, amazingly it works. There is clearly some kind of stateful bug in the object `ConvexHullMesh` produces which is exposed when calling `dodCH["Faces"]` and disappears after running `BoundaryMeshRegion@Dodecahedron[]`

Comment: That’s an interesting observation. Thanks. That explains why I was having such trouble making the post—I’d run the code to make sure that my post made sense. it would work and then run it again and it wouldn’t.  Bizarre bug.

Comment: Indeed bizarre. As most of the other `"Properties"` of `MeshRegion`s. An efficient workaround in this case would be the (also undocumented) `MeshCells[dodCH, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]`.