# How to display full 3D region?

Tags: bugs, graphics3d, regions

Answers to an earlier posting, [ConvexHullMesh inconsistency](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226122/194),
have let me construct a particular 3D region by intersecting a pyramid with a halfspace:

```
Rint = RegionIntersection[Rhalfspace, RPyramid]
```

The construction is correct, and the region displays like this
upon executing the above command:

---

[image: Rint]

---

The slanted plane is (correctly) caused by `Rhalfspace`. The two vertical planes are caused by some
type of plotrange clipping. My question is simple:

> ***Q***. How do I display the full region?

I've tried `RegionPlot3D`, `DiscretizeRegion`, but nothing I try allows me to e.g., use `PlotRange`. I am missing something basic about how to convert a region to a 3D graphics object.

---

```
Rhalfspace = HalfSpace[{0.694747,0.186157,0.694747},{0.622008,0.166667,0.333333}];

pts={{1., 0., 0.}, {0.866025, 0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.866025, 0.}, {0., 1., 
  0.}, {-0.5, 0.866025, 0.}, {-0.866025, 0.5, 0.}, {-1., 0., 
  0.}, {-0.866025, -0.5, 0.}, {-0.5, -0.866025, 0.}, {0., -1., 
  0.}, {0.5, -0.866025, 0.}, {0.866025, -0.5, 0.}, {0., 0., 2.}};

RPyramid = Region[BoundaryMesh[DelaunayMesh[pts]]]

Rint = RegionIntersection[Rhalfspace, RPyramid]
```

---

***Added***. Following @flinty's use of `ImplicitRegion`:

[image: Rint2]

Comment: What did `DiscretizeRegion` say? Please post the errors and give something we can execute, as we don't have `Rhalfspace`, `RPyramid`. If you have the mesh from `mesh = DiscretizeRegion[...]` then that _is the whole mesh_ - To embed in `Graphics3D` just put it in there `Graphics3D[{mesh}]`

Comment: @flinty: OK, will include code. Will take a bit ...

Comment: @flinty: `Graphics3D[{Rint}]` says Region is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive.

Comment: Yes you have to discretize it first.

Comment: @flinty: `DiscretizeRegion` was unable to discretize the region

Comment: `SolidRegionQ[Rhalfspace]` is `False` - instead of intersecting with a HalfSpace, use a big cuboid instead. These operations with `HalfSpace` crash on my machine 12.1.1 after the first run.

Comment: ^ in fact don't bother with that approach, I tried it and Mathematica will not even discretize a rotated cuboid properly either! https://pastebin.com/db1jLHpd

Comment: This works: `reg = ImplicitRegion[-3 < {0.694747, 0.186157, 
       0.694747}.({x, y, z} - {0.622008, 0.166667, 0.333333}) < 
     0 && -2 < x < 2 && -2 < y < 2 && -2 < z < 2, {x, y, z}];` then `RegionIntersection[DiscretizeRegion@reg, RPyramid]`

Comment: I think it's a bug and should be reported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appear to be some problems using `HalfSpace`. I've worked around this using an `ImplicitRegion` instead that matches up with the `HalfSpace` but produces a bounded object when discretized:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[-3 < {0.694747, 0.186157, 
       0.694747}.({x, y, z} - {0.622008, 0.166667, 0.333333}) < 
     0 && -2 < x < 2 && -2 < y < 2 && -2 < z < 2, {x, y, z}];

RegionIntersection[DiscretizeRegion@reg, RPyramid]
```

This produces the full part of the cone you wanted with the top removed:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for experimenting! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

If I do the following incantation:

```
bounds = RegionBounds[Rint]

(*  {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {0., 2.}}  *)

Append[Rint, PlotRange -> %]
```

I get this:

[image]

This also often succeeds:

```
Append[Rint, PlotRange -> {{-1.`, 1.`}, {-1.`, 1.`}, {0.`, 2.`}}]
```

Either of these has usually failed in my trials (runs until I kill the kernel; succeeded only once each in say a dozen or more tries):

```
Append[Rint, PlotRange -> bounds]
Append[Rint, PlotRange -> RegionBounds[Rint]]
```

Sometimes, I have to kill the kernel twice: When it restarts, it hangs when it computes `Rint`.

Doing the first command multiple times (or any of the commands, if they succeed at first) ultimately hangs the kernel.

Comment: Could you explain the use of `Append` here? Why does it work to append graphics options to a region?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke From the docs for `Region`: "Region has the same options as Graphics for embedding dimension 2 and the same options as Graphics3D for embedding dimension 3, with the following additions and changes...."  You can also add them to `RegionIntersection` and probably most other region operations, but in your example, the kernel always hangs for me, and I have to kill it.